# Numerical Solution for this equation

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, boundary-conditions

I want to solve this equation in Mathematica then plot x[t]:

```
ClearAll[y, x, a, b, k, f]
a = 1; b = 0.24; k = 0.002; f = 0.68;
eqn1 = {x''[t]/x[t] + (3 a/2 - 1) (x'[x]/x[t])^2 -3b/2 (x'[t]/x[t])+k ((3 a-1)/2 ) x[t]^-2 - a*f==0};
NDSolve[{eq1,x[1]==1,x'[1]==x0},x,t]
```

Comment: Have you looked up the documentation for `NDSolve` and followed the examples there?

Comment: yes i did, but just for the first part:

numbsol = 
 NDSolve[{ 
   x*y[x]*y'[x] + (3 a)/2 (y[x] - b/(2 a))^2 + 
     k ((3 a)/2 - 1) x^-2 - ((3 a*f)/2 + (3 b^2)/(8 a)) == 0, 
   y[1] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 30}]
Plot[y[x] /. numbsol, {x, 1, 30}, PlotRange -> All]

Comment: Your equations are confusing.  You have `x` as both an integration variable *and* as a function of `t`.  You are not specifying the range of `t`.  Can you please clarify?  (This is why I asked!  We can't help if we don't know what you've done and where you're stuck.  Please edit your post with the extra code rather than putting it in a comment.)

Comment: This is the relation between y[x], y[t]=x'[t]/x[t] and range for t is [0.1,10]

Comment: Yes I saw that.  But in your `NDSolve` call, you are using `x` as the integration variable, when perhaps it should be `t`?

Comment: There are other things, too.  For instance, in the code you pasted into the comment, you have `af` when it should be `a f` instead of `a*f`, which will cause the thing not to work.  This is another reason why you should add it to the original post so that you can see where issues might be.

Comment: You cannot use `NDSolve` to solve for `y` if you have defined `y` to be something else.

Comment: I think y'[t]=(x''[t]x[t]-x'[t]^2)/x^2

Comment: It might be that you just need to include more information in your post besides just the code.  *What* are you trying to do, what you are you trying to solve for, are the really two independent functions here (`y[x]` and `x[t]`). Etc.  The problem with the code is that it's just entirely unclear what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yes a*f this is correct

Comment: NDSolve[{eq1==0,x[1]==1,y[1]==1},x,t]

Comment: `eq2` seems irrelevant. Why is it included in the post?  And `eq1` is a typo?

Comment: `NDSolve[{eqn1, y[1] == 1}, y, {x, 0.1, 1}]` works fine for me. Any chance that's what you want?

Comment: I want to plot base on time t

Comment: Change the t to {t,0.1,1} — it can’t guess the range for t. You have to tell it. See the examples in the docs for NDSolve

Comment: it's not working for me!!!

Comment: Adjusting [my previous comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/266031/numerical-solution-for-this-equation#comment663183_266031) to the *new* equation, try `a = 1; b = 0.24; k = 0.002; f = 0.68;
NDSolve[{x''[t]*x[t] + (3 a/2 - 1) (x'[t])^2 - 3 b/2 (x'[t]*x[t]) + k ((3 a - 1)/2) - a*f x[t]^2 == 0, x[1] == 1, x'[1] == 0}, x, {t,  0, 10}]` -- You seem not to understand two things: (1) How to set up a numerical ode mathematically (need boundary conditions) and (2) how to follow the syntax in the documentation for `NDSolve`. That seems to be why you're having difficulty.

Answer (score 4):

Like this?

```
ClearAll[y, x, a, b, k, f]
a = 1; b = 0.24; k = 0.002; f = 0.68; x0 = .1;
eqn1 = x''[t]/x[t] + (3 a/2 - 1) (x'[t]/x[t])^2 - 3 b/2 (x'[t]/x[t]) +
     k ((3 a - 1)/2) x[t]^-2 - a*f == 0;
sol = NDSolve[{eqn1, x[1] == 1, x'[1] == x0}, x, {t, 0, 10}]
fx = x /. sol[[1, 1]]
Plot[fx[t], {t, 0, 10}]
```

Comment: This is not working!!!!

Comment: @FelipeDura it works for me. Make sure to clear everything before `ClearAll[y, x, a, b, k, f,t]`

Comment: I have mathematica for mac.

Comment: @FelipeDura For me everything works too and I have a mac. Restart mathematica kernel.